# Displaying on screen without being recordable by another app

Tags: drm, screen-capture

A couple years ago I rented a movie on iTunes and began watching it in the Windows 10 x64 desktop app.

At one point, I opened OBS in capture screen mode. To my amazement, the iTunes window showed only black content in OBS's preview and recording — despite being clearly displayed on the screen at the same time, thus ruling out simple app detection and hiding. (That at least is how I remember it.)

I didn't know this was possible. How is it? Do they circumvent the driver or something?

Comment: Is it perfect black (`#000000`) or a different color close to it (like `#010101`)? At least in old versions of Windows video players often rendered into some kind of hardware overlay, which would then show where the normal display buffer contained the mask color. Screenshots would only contain the content of the normal display buffer (i.e. the mask color), appearing black. No idea if that still applies in newer versions of windows. This was done for performance reasons, not as DRM.

Comment: This is also happening with Netflix (and I believe many other streaming services). You can't take screenshots of Netflix video, it'll appear black.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Rendering video using [hardware overlays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/hardware-overlay-support) is still very much a thing in current versions of Windows (and other OSes as well), at least as long as decoding is done in software.

Comment: @TooTea: It's even more likely to be done using hardware blending if decoding is GPU-assisted (decode into a texture that's used to render a scene, or decode into a layer buffer that's used for overlay)

Comment: I feel it needs to be pointed how how *insanely* insecure it is for any OS to allow usermode access to graphical output the OS is sending to hardware without explicit permission from the user. It's so massively dangerous for absolutely no good reason; only a tiny proportion of programs - mostly OCR/accessibility screenreaders and screensharing programs - should *ever* need to know that information.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's an OS / driver-level function, yes. The screen recorder app isn't literally recording the screen, obviously - for that it would need hardware either in the display or in front of it - so what it's doing instead is either querying the OS for the current framebuffer, or using a virtual hardware driver to create a virtual second monitor in mirror mode and capturing the traffic sent to it.

To defeat the first, a playback app can simply tell the OS that it's not to appear in the framebuffer captures. A compromised video driver could capture it (since the video device obviously needs the real framebuffer) but the OS can just lie to user-mode software about what's on the screen. To defeat the second, the app can query what displays it is running on, and refuse to render on displays that it believes may be copying content. Obviously, a driver could spoof the identity of a trusted display, but this would likely invite lawsuits.

---

There is, separately, a mechanism for preventing captures in the "monitor" connected to the video output. Like most DRM, [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) has been broken, but will still stop people who aren't trying very hard. However, for software captures, I think HDCP doesn't enter into it, and everything depends on OS/driver support.

Comment: "the app can query what displays it is running on, and refuse to render on displays that it believes may be copying content" - this issue sometimes occurs with USB display adapters, and results in the playback controls being visible atop an all-black video, just like you see on OBS.

Comment: Defeating the first doesn't even need to be deliberate: historically, graphics cards/drivers have had split pipelines.  Traditional drawing (such as windows and text) went through the bitmap pipeline, while 3d graphics went through the rendering pipeline.  Since screenshot software generally queried the bitmap framebuffer, screenshots of games (and video players that used the rendering pipeline) would be blank.

Comment: For option 1 you clearly state that the OS needs to cooperate for this to work. Is option 2 something the app can do on its own or does it also require an OS to support this feature?

Comment: @quarague Option 2 requires that the OS provide an API for "what displays am I showing on?", and a way to block out part of the framebuffer for that display (either directly in the framebuffer, or by altering the render pipeline for the app on that display). These are reasonably likely features for a modern graphical OS but it'd take me some research to make it work even if the relevant APIs exist. Driver-based capture is probably less common anyhow; it's more complicated and delicate code, more liable to be blocked by signature enforcement, and might need an HDCP bypass (illegal under DMCA).